# Name badges per-site

Tags: discussion, badges

I think the badge names are actually *very* generic.  This was either quite clever and by someone who had a lot of foresight (applying same badges to multiple sites!) or just someone giving out plain badge names.

You could have names for specific sites.  There could be badges like `TeXpert` on tex.stackexchange.com, `linguist` on english.stackexchange.com, `ninja` on gamedev.stackex, and I don't know what else.

Comment: And under what criteria should we use to determine when these badges should be awarded? Or if you're proposing replacing existing badge names, then which badges should be renamed?

Comment: well there are the tag badges which are site specific but I don't think that what you meant